# How can I position the last element at the end of the column using flexbox?

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to use flexbox to position the last item at the bottom of the vertical navbar. Is there a way to do this using flexbox?

[image: navbar]

Here is the code example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<style>
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
 ul {
    list-style: none;
    background: red;
    width: 100px;
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
 }

 li {
    border: 1px solid blue;
 }

 li:last-child {
    background: blue;
    align-self: end;
 }

</style>
<body>
<ul>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>foo</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`margin-top: auto` will push it to the bottom. You can read more about auto margin's and flexbox here - https://hackernoon.com/flexbox-s-best-kept-secret-bd3d892826b6

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<style>
  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  ul {
    list-style: none;
    background: red;
    width: 100px;
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
  }
  
  li {
    border: 1px solid blue;
  }
  
  li:last-child {
    background: blue;
    margin-top: auto;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>foo</li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```